# Locus of a point - sum of distance from two points

Tags: conic-sections, locus

Find the locus of the point $P$ such that the sum of its distances from $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$ is $6$.

What I did:
I tried using the distance formula, but I think that's too much of a task. There has to be an easier way. Please point me in the right direction. I do think that the locus is going to be an ellipse.

Comment: You were on the right track. Maybe there is a more efficient way to simplify the equation, but, that is about it.

Comment: Yes but I don't get how its possible to get the simple answer that they give from it.

Comment: Take one of the distances to the other side of the equality, and only then take a square on both sides. Probably many of the terms would cancel out. Do some algebraic manipulation, and then, maybe you need to do one more square after that.
I will try to think of an easier way also.

Comment: Btw, I have forgotten a lot of high school maths, but it seems that it is a property of an ellipse that, the sum of the distances of any point on it from it's loci is constant.

Comment: Check out page 2 form this link
http://www.mcclenahan.info/sfhs/Algebra2/LectureNotes/9-4_Ellipses.pdf

Comment: Exactly but I can't remember the formula used to describe an ellipse @Juanito

Answer (score 4):

That is exactly how you are intended to find the locus:  let $(x,y)$ be a point in the locus $P$.  Then $$\sqrt{x^2 + (y-2)^2} + \sqrt{x^2 + (y+2)^2} = 6.$$  Squaring both sides and simplifying, we get $$\begin{align*} 36 &= x^2 + (y-2)^2 + 2 \sqrt{(x^2 + (y-2)^2)(x^2 + (y+2)^2)} + x^2 + (y+2)^2 \\ &= 2x^2 + 2y^2 + 8 + 2\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+4-4y)(x^2+y^2+4+4y)} .\end{align*}$$  Now move terms to the LHS, divide by $2$, and square:  $$(14-x^2-y^2)^2 = (x^2+y^2+4)^2 - (4y)^2$$  Now rearrange and use again the difference of squares factorization:  $$(4y)^2 = (x^2+y^2+4)^2 - (x^2+y^2-14)^2 = 18(2x^2+2y^2-10),$$ from which we obtain $$4y^2 = 9(x^2+y^2-5)$$ or $$9x^2+5y^2 = 45.$$

Comment: Well that's a long procedure. Anyways thank you. However, I finally found out how to obtain the formula for an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Start with $\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+2)^2}=6$, and then rewrite this as $\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}=6-\sqrt{x^2+(y+2)^2}$.

Then square both sides, isolate the remaining square root, divide by -4, and then square both sides again.

---

Another way to do this is to first find points $(0,a)$ and $(0,-a)$ on the y-axis which satisfy the given condition, and then find points $(b,0)$ and $(-b,0)$ which also satisfy this condition.

Then you could use the form $\frac{x^2}{b^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}=1$ for the ellipse, since it has center at the origin and axes which are parallel to the coordinate axes.