# A curve consists of all of the points $(x, y)$ in the Cartesian plane with the sum of the distances from $(x, y)$ to $(1, 0)$ and to $(−1, 0)$ is 4

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

A curve consists of all of the points $(x, y)$ in the Cartesian plane such that the sum of  the distances from $(x, y)$ to $(1, 0)$ and to $(−1, 0)$ is $4$.

Find an equation for the curve  that does not employ square roots.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Locus of a point - sum of distance from two points](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878091/locus-of-a-point-sum-of-distance-from-two-points)

Comment: What effort have you made ?

Answer (score 3):

This should help you:

[image]

The rest will follow...

Comment: [+1] I don't know if "the rest will follow" for the OP, but I like the drawing.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't really appreciate homework questions in general, but sometimes questions are not being helpful.